# Get access to multiple gmail accounts in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

I'm creating a Chrome extension that modifies the gmail UI.
But when I authenticate (with chrome.identity.getAuthToken) in the Chrome extension, it defaults to using the user account that is signed into Chrome.

But I need data for a gmail account when I am on that gmail page.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675959/login-to-chrome-extension-with-a-google-user-other-than-the-one-in-use-by-chrome) answer, but I was wondering if there was any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through the same process and I couldn't find an easier way.

You'll need to authenticate yourself.

We tried using the mechanism in that link but it requires putting the Client Secret in the Extension - very ugly.

In the end we request and refresh tokens externally through a hosted web page from our www site.

Although a hassle to set up once in place it works nicely and is worth the effort.